# Clang equivalent of GCC's __builtin_darn()

Tags: clang, llvm, powerpc, altivec

I'm trying to discover Clang's equivalent to [GCC's `__builtin_darn()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-PowerPC-Built-in-Functions-Available-on-ISA-3_002e0.html) on Power9. Grepping Clang 7.0 sources it looks like LLVM supports it:

```
llvm_source$ cat llvm/test/MC/PowerPC/ppc64-encoding.s | grep darn -B 1 -A 1

# CHECK-BE: darn 2, 3                       # encoding: [0x7c,0x43,0x05,0xe6]
# CHECK-LE: darn 2, 3                       # encoding: [0xe6,0x05,0x43,0x7c]
            darn 2, 3
```

However, I can't seen to find the builtin:

```
llvm_source$ grep -IR darn | grep builtin
llvm_source$
```

What is Clang equivalent of GCC's `__builtin_darn()`?

Answer (score 1):

This was [merged into LLVM 12.0.0-rc1](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/5e85a2ba1645c3edbf26bba096631fbd318ada47), so it's likely to be available in llvm/clang 12.

Answer (score 0):

You could write in in extended ASM (which you've already done probably):

```
void t2()
{
    static unsigned int x;
    asm __volatile__("darn %0,1": "=r" (x));
}
```

your bug ref: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39800